# Hangover after drinking Kviek brew?

Tags: fermentation, hangover

I recently brewed a batch of pale ale using Kveik yeast (Omega Voss OYL-061). I fermented in primary at 29 degrees for about 14 days before kegging - it was oxygenated well and went absolutely wild in the first 3 days. It turn out at 5.6% ABV. The beer tastes good - I'm not getting any acetaldehyde flavor - but I only drank just under a liter and woke up with a terrible headache. Does Kveik still produce a lot of fusels under certain conditions?

Comment: I don't know a lot about kveik, but I'll bet it produces some fusels.  And you might be sensitive to that.  Could also be dehydration.  It's rare but I get headaches if I don't drink enough water and/or I drink too much alcohol in one session.  How much did you have that night?  Could it have been anything else, or could it have been just too much in a binge?  Rhetorical, you don't need to answer.

Comment: Did you use any brewing salts / water treatments?

Comment: @rob I put 1/2tsp of gypsum in the mash

Comment: Apparently the problem could have been that I overpitched. I’ve learned that Kveik actually works better when slightly stressed.

Answer (score 2):

Hangover is still not clearly understood but one dominant factor is dehydration due to over-consumption of alcohol resulting in, most commoly, headache and nausea. There are other symptoms of hangover that will be difficult to distinguish from most forms of over-consumtion of alcohol and other symptoms of allergic reactions and other over sensitivities including other non-alcohol related reactions. See the Wikipedia [hangover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangover) page for further links to other sources. In short, it is not certainly an effect of hangover experienced, there may be other reasons for the reaction.

Answer (score 0):

I brewed 90 litres (10 X 9L batches) last Australian summer using Lallemand Voss Kveik Ale Yeast (dry yeast) and was very satisfied with the results, experiencing no ill effects. Brewing with it again as I type this